# I had a redirect loop on my MVC 4 Razor website

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Essentially, I found the problem to be that I was using

```
@typeof (WebModule).Assembly.GetName().Version
```

to get the version number of the assembly in order to display on our website. Changing this to

```
@typeof(WebModule).Assembly.GetName().Version
```

fixed the problem. My question is: why would a syntax error like this on an MVC Razor view not cause a server error like any other View syntax error. Why does that cause a redirect loop?

Comment: What's the difference, apart from the space (which is irrelevant)? What makes you think this code caused the redirect loop, and not for example your error handling code?

Comment: The space isn't irrelevant. It's a syntax error. What are your talking about? I have no error handling code.

Comment: You're right, in Razor syntax the space is relevant as it will expect `()` directly after `typeof`. Still, a syntax error does not cause a redirect, hence no redirect loop, unless you have error handling in place.

Comment: To CodeCaster's point, an exception is an exception and has no relevance on when/how a redirect loop is created.  An exception is occurring causing *something else* to redirect.  That redirect is configured incorrectly as it's causing a redirect loop.  It could be something as simple as an `ErrorHandlerAttribute` redirecting to `/Error/Index` and that method also has a error causing a redirect to `/Error/Index`.